# How to get or address a single event of a event series of a Google calendar by GAS

Tags: google-apps-script, google-calendar-api

In a Google calendar events have a unique id, but does the event of an event series have one, too? I need to handle each event of an event series differently. The regular way to address an event is:

```
let now      = new Date();
let until    = new Date(2023, 10, 25);
let calendar = CalendarApp.getCalendarById("678fbf4f44afb7cdsomething@resource.calendar.google.com");
let events   = calendar.getEvents(now, until); // returns an array of all events within this period of time
// Make a list of all event id:
for (i=0; i<events.length; i++) {
  console.log("event" + i + " has id " + events[i].getId());
}
```

Although events of an event series have all the same event id I can address them reliably by the variable's index, eg. `events[3]` as long as the variable `events` is alive.

**Verbose example:**

Assuming there is a series of five events of one event series within one day:

```
2022-11-03 11:18 (= event[0])
2022-11-03 12:22 (= event[1])
2022-11-03 13:15 (= event[2])
2022-11-03 13:30 (= event[3])
2022-11-03 14:00 (= event[4])
```

Having these indexes I can create Google forms to collect food orderings to the single events and I can add a guest to [2] and change the room of [2] and [3]:

```
2022-11-03 11:18 (= event[0])
2022-11-03 12:22 (= event[1])
2022-11-03 13:15 (= event[2]) - added Mr. Smith, set location: Ball Room
2022-11-03 13:30 (= event[3]) - set location: Ball Room
2022-11-03 14:00 (= event[4])
```

Then someone uses the calendar GUI to rightfully shift the time of some events which are varying by details and thus distinguishable now:

```
2022-11-03 11:18 (= event[0])
2022-11-03 12:22 (= event[1])
2022-11-03 11:30 (= event[2]) - added Mr. Smith, set location: Ball Room
2022-11-03 15:30 (= event[3]) - set location: Ball Room
2022-11-03 14:00 (= event[4])
```

Running a new getEvents will return

```
2022-11-03 11:18 (= event[0], formerly event[0])
2022-11-03 11:30 (= event[1], formerly event[2]) - with added Mr. Smith and location Ball Room
2022-11-03 12:22 (= event[2], formerly event[1])
2022-11-03 14:00 (= event[3], formerly event[4])
2022-11-03 15:30 (= event[4], formerly event[3]) - with location Ball Room
```

How can I now address a specific event of that series, for example to sync them with their corresponding forms? Do the events of an event series have some kind of a fixed "sub event id"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find in the official doc this statement

> Note that the icalUID and the id are not identical and only one of
> them should be supplied at event creation time. One difference in
> their semantics is that in recurring events, all occurrences of one
> event have different ids while they all share the same icalUIDs.

([link](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/events))

So yes, an occurrence of a recurring event has its own id (its `id` property).

The problem with Apps Script is that the method `getId()` actually retrieves the `iCalUID` property of an event, not its unique id. So using the `CalendarApp` service, all occurrences will have the same id ([doc](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar-event#getId())).

Try using the [advanced Calendar service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/calendar) and you'll be able to list events, get their unique id, get their iCalUID and so on.

Comment: Very helpful. Thank You very much! I found out, that the unique identifier for event instances (i. e. events of an event series) is what you get with `event.id`, and that it is a combination of the iCalUID and the time when the instance originally took place (when the date has not been altered). The latter is somehow confusing as it shows a different startdate. :-)